# User Input Not Responding With If/Else Statements Correctly

Tags: python

I'm working through Learning Python the Hard Way and I'm currently creating a game. For some reason my if/else statements are not properly working. Here is the related part in my current script:

```
if door_choice == '1':
    room_one()
else:
    print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"

if door_choice == '2':
    room_two()
else:
    print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"

if door_choice == '3':
    room_three()
else:
    print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"
```

Whatever number I use to type in my input, I still receive the other answers' else statement, for example:

```
You see 3 doors.
You must choose either 1, 2 or 3.
> 2
I don't recognize that choice, try again!
The second room is dark and smelly but you see a gold chest!
Do you open the chest or just give up?
I don't recognize that choice, try again!
```

The print statement for "I don't recognize that choice, try again!" should not show up if I input the designated number. I tried adding integer to my input and having my door choice variable not as a string and still no luck.

Comment: Put a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1):

You should chain those separate `if-else` blocks into one `if-elif-else` block:

```
if door_choice == '1':
    room_one()
elif door_choice == '2':
    room_two()
elif door_choice == '3':
    room_three()
else:
    print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help, that makes more sense and is a lot cleaner to read. Are there any maximums to be watchful of for how many elif I could include?

Comment: I'm not sure of any maximums, but in the case of a substantial number, you should consider using a dictionary, accessed using the value of `door_choice`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your if statements. Your program encounters `if door_choice == '1'` which is false, so it jumps to the next else statement and prints `"I don't recognize that choice, try again!"`

Instead if first is not true, then check second, if not true check third, if not true, invalid choice.

```
if door_choice == '1':
    room_one()
elif door_choice == '2':
    room_two()
elif door_choice == '3':
    room_three()  
else:
    print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious "pass in else everytime" effect, you can use a table and function pointers to save the if/elif constructions if you have a lot of cases.

```
room_funcs = [room_one,room_two,room_three]
idx = int(door_choice)-1
if 0 <= idx < len(room_funcs):
   room_funcs[idx]()
else:
   print("I don't recognize that choice, try again!")
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach.

Comment: thanks. As Moses says, and if you want to get rid of numerical input but prefer North, West, East ... you can put the function pointers in a dictionary it's almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
If door_choice == '1'
  Room_one()
elif door_choice == '2'
  Room_two()
elif door_choice == '3'
  Room_three()
else
  Print "please input a value between 1 and 3
```

You had some bad logics.
If you input 1, then that's correct otherwise error appears, however you check again for input 2 and get the wished result and then check again for input 3 but error appears again.

Using else if or elif in python is one of the way to get to the result.
There are also switches if you need to do more cases

Comment: you need lowercase on your elif and else statements

Comment: Ikr, but my Android device decided to automatically put them in caps, and I didn't notice :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As for maximums there is one `if` statement, chained by any amount of `elif` statements. However, there can only be 1 `else` statements per `if`.

TutorialsPoint has a great page regarding if/elif/else: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

"The else statement is an optional statement and there could be at most only one else statement following if ."

I don't think your indentation is right. Indent all of the else statements by 4 spaces additionally after the `if` statements, and change them to `if`. Also take away the last `else` statement.

I'll show you what I mean.

```
if door_choice == '1':
    room_one()
    if door_choice != 1 or 2 or 3:
        print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"

if door_choice == '2':
    room_two()
    if door_choice != 1 or 2 or 3:
        print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"

if door_choice == '3':
    room_three()
    if door_choice != 1 or 2 or 3:
        print "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"
```

Also, your not giving the user input after you say "I don't recognize that choice, try again!"

Comment: I know that this code is inefficient, but it is the structure that you have first proposed. This can easily be done with less lines/characters.